# Backup folder view settings

Tags: windows-7

Is there any way to backup the changes we've made to folders view settings?

Every time I re-install Windows (Windows7 x64) I need to reapply my preferred view settings to all folders (Books, Movies, Photos etc...)

The mentioned preferred setting is different for folders, so I can't use folder templates here. I just need to backup settings somehow, or get Windows to store view settings in `desktop.ini` or something.

**Update**

In case someone needed one-click backup for these settings:

```
regedit /E "C:\BackupFoldersViewSettings.reg" "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell"
```

Save this as a `.bat` file and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows saves the folder view settings in registry.

They are located at:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\BagMRU`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags`

To access them, you need to use **regedit** by pressing `start > run > type regedit and enter`.
In there you have the option to export a registry folder which can later be imported (backup/restore).

I would also make a backup of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\` just to be safe.

**Update**: For Win7-x64 the registry locations are:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagsMRU`